# Calling spring boot webservice from angularjs with get method, is not working is giving 500 status error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring-boot, web-services

I have created a webservice to get the excel file from server location to my local machine. with the help of  springboot and angularjs. Now my URL is generating well, but i am getting 500 error.
my code is given below ..

My Springboot class:

```
    class MyWebserviceClass
    
        {
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "digital_data/{digital_file}", produces = "application/vnd.ms-excel")
        public getExcelFileFromServer((HttpServletResponse response, @PathVariable("digital_file") String digital_file) throws IOException {
        {
        // my download logic will we here
        }
```

**AngularJS controller method**

```
digitalService.getDigitalData(digital_file).then (function(res) {

                    var blob = new Blob([res.data], {type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"});
                    
                    saveDigitalData(blob, digital_file);

                }, function(errRes) {
                    $scope.showErrorMessage("Error");
                
                })
            };
```

**AngularJS Service Layer**

```
digitalService
{
 function getDigitalData(digital_file) {
            var url = 'digital_data/'+file_name;
            return $http.get(url,{
                        transformRequest: angular.identity,
                        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
                        responseType:"arraybuffer"
                    });
                        
        }
    }
```

After running this code, web service URL generating properly but code is not able to call springboot webservice.

Generated URL: **http://localhost:8080/RMS/digital_data/user_review.xlsx**

**Error:**

**{resStatus: -3, appErrorMsg: "Could not find acceptable representation"}**

Exception:
com.media.MediaController.MyWebservice.getExcelFileFromServer(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,java.lang.String) throws java.io.IOException={[/digital_data/{digital_file}],methods=[GET],produces=[application/vnd.ms-excel]}}

could you guys please help me, as this is my first webservice . it might be possible i am doing some silly mistake..
And sorry for typo mistake...

Comment: The return type for `getExcelFileFromServer` is missing. If it is a byte[] (raw file), you can add `@ResponseBody` to the method to tell spring not to convert it (cause of "Could not find acceptable representation").

If you ever want to return other data than excel, you might want to look at ResponseEntity<byte[]> or something similar as a return type.

Comment: thanks Ken, It would be void as i am downloading on my machine..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I removed the file extension from the filename for URL, and added into springboot functionality.
Example: URL would be **http://localhost:8080/RMS/digital_data/user_review** instead of **http://localhost:8080/RMS/digital_data/user_review.xlsx**.. and it is working fine.